# Error al iniciar proyecto de React Native en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, react-native

estoy iniciando en el mundo de desarrollo de apps movil, y tengo un problema al usar el sgte comando `npm run android`. Me salta el sgte error: `Failed to launch emulator. Reason No emulators found as a output of 'emulador' -list-avds`. Pueden ver el error en la sgte imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con `expo` y funciona correctamente pero para cargar un proyecto desde mi celular con su aplicacion se demora mucho y es tedioso esperar, por eso he probado con Android Studio, pero me resulta este error, he buscado información y parece ser por una variable de entorno. La verdad no tengo idea que se debe hacer para resolver este problema. Gracias por su asesoramiento.

Comment: Para crear proyectos es con npx create-react-native-ap.... para correrlo igual npx react-native run-android

Comment: Viendo tu error ahi te dice te falta una variable de java home en windows esas variables se la pone en click derecho a MIPC y algunas de las pestañas dice variables algo asi, no recuerdo bien, pon javahome para tu usuario o global  y el path seria tu direccion de java de android creo busca en internet configurar variable javahome

Comment: Hola, perdon por no haber contestado, estaba ocupado con asuntos personales y no estado entrado al sitio, pude resolver el problema, ahora estoy intentando conectar via wifi un proyecto de react native de mi pc a mi telefono, y resulta que tengo un problema, si deseas ayudarme: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/432420/no-se-puede-conectar-via-wifi-un-proyecto-de-react-native